# Is "undefinedRouteEvaluation" significant?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I've got an IoT Hub, message routing feeding two event hubs in one namespace, and two functions trying to read from those two event hubs. Sometimes only one function gets called, sometimes neither. So I'm trying to learn how to debug these issues. In storage explorer I found insights-logs-routes, and I'm wondering is this significant:

```
  "operationName": "undefinedRouteEvaluation",
  "category": "Routes",
  "level": "Information",
  "properties": "{\"deviceId\":\"EAxxx\",\"endpointName\":null,\"messageId\":null,\"details\":null,\"routeName\":\"checkinroute\",\"statusCode\":null}",
```

Does the "undefined" part of that mean that I'm missing something? Google can't find "undefinedRouteEvaluation" anywhere.

The messages definitely get sent from the device to the IoTHub, the vscode extension can see them. And half of the routing works ... sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen these errors in my logs and also cannot find anything in the webs about them, and I've also had issues with routes resolution.

In my case it turned out that I was defining routes on message body `$body.SomeProperty='some string value'` but this 'style' is supported only when the JSON document coming from the device has additional information about encoding. If this information is missing the route will not be resolved and the messages will flow the the fallback route.

To correct the problem I had to define route query on `applicationProperties` part of the message (in my case all the properties from the message body were passed to the `applicationProperties` dictionary automagically). The query had to become `SomeProperty='some string value'`.

Now it routes work fine and stably.